# Automatically Voice Recording when Voice starts and playback when the voice stops

Tags: objective-c, ios

Can anyone help me for the following :

Record voice automatically and play when silent for sometime like talking tom. Can anyone help me to identify the logic behind talking tom. When the user starts to speak, it should record automatically and when the user stops speaking, then the recorded voice should be playback. How this can be do? Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
float peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [soundRecorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
float averagePowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [soundRecorder averagePowerForChannel:0]));
lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;  
averagePassResults = ALPHA * averagePowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * averagePassResults;

if (peakPowerForChannel > 0.08f) {
    [soundRecorder recordForDuration:5];
} else {
    NSLog(@"not audible");
}
```

Comment: value of ALPHA is "0.5"

Comment: Sorry,, I m using Dirac Framework to play the recorded voice.... i haven't found averagePowerForChannel... Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you have to analyze your audio stream and when a certain peak value defined as "signal" was hit and held for some time, you would start the recording.

When another defined value defined as "silence" is appearing for some time, you would need to stop recording and start playback.

Actually a pure signal processing task.
Not complex in theory. Never done this on an iPhone though.

Hope this helps,

best,

Flo